# The type arguments cannot be inferred from the query

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

my linq query works, I tested in the linqpad, got result back. the error happened at the last step, when I try to use EntityVM ViewModel.  I dont really understand what this error message means. can someone please explain that to me, and show me how to fix it. thank you.

**Error Message: "the type arguments cannot be inferred from the query"**

```
        var entityVersions = EntityVersionRepository.Get().Where(x => x.Entity.ClientId == clientId);


        var groups = from ev in entityVersions
                     group ev by ev.EntityId
                         into g
                         select g.OrderByDescending(x => x.TaxYear).FirstOrDefault();

        var result = from g in groups
                     select (en => new EntityVM
                                       {
                                           Name = en.EntityName,
                                           Id = en.EntityId  
                                       });
```

Comment: sorry, its in the title, forget to put it in the post.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it could be because you aren't actually evaluating the `groups` query (by calling `.ToList()` or something similar). Try evaluating `groups` first:

```
var groups = (from ev in entityVersions
                 group ev by ev.EntityId
                     into g
                     select g.OrderByDescending(x => x.TaxYear).FirstOrDefault())
             .ToList();
```

If this is the problem, then it's probably a prime example of why you shouldn't use var when you're returning concrete types from a query. If you'd of changed `var groups` to `List<Group> groups`, that code wouldn't of even compiled, so you'd have known straight away that you hadn't actually evaluated the property (it would of returned an `IQueryable<Group>` instead).